# Razor ASP.NET Core HTML Tag Helper Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I had an error in regarding with the razor code and this is the error pops up:

```
'IEnumerable<Employee>' does not contain a definition for 'FullName' and no extension method 'FullName' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<Employee>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

As further checking, this error only occurs on

```
<label asp-for="FullName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <input asp-for="FullName" class="form-control"/>
    <span asp-validation-for="FullName" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

All other razor file is okay... the problem is something to do with asp-for and I don't know why.

Also I call my models through my class library which is this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Demo101.DAL.Entities.Models.Employee>
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this TagHelper is the problem. According to the error message you call the property Age on a instance of the IEnumerable<Employee> type. I don't know if the IEnumerable<Employee> is your model for the razor view or just one of the properties of another model. You just need to find where exactly you call the property that does not exist in this particular type.

Comment: Your error references the property Age, but you are showing the helper tag for FullName - are you sure you're showing where the issue actually originated?

Comment: Hi @Tacud, I already updated the question... I don't know if it is something to do with the razor or the model from the class library itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I just remove the `IEnumerable<>` and it works perfectly right now! Thank you for your help @Tacud and @sleeyuen.